# Problem with MongoDB Ruby Driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm on Ubuntu, and I've done

```
install gem mongo
```

which reported

```
Successfully installed bson-1.0
Successfully installed mongo-1.0
2 gems installed
```

I've started mongod

Now I cd to the mongo gem directory and try

```
> ruby examples/simple.rb
```

and I get the error

```
./examples/../lib/mongo.rb:31:in `require': no such file to load -- bson (LoadError)
    from ./examples/../lib/mongo.rb:31
    from examples/simple.rb:3:in `require'
    from examples/simple.rb:3
```

which I can't make sense of, since the bson gem is installed

```
> gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bson (1.0)
bson_ext (1.0)
mongo (1.0)
rack (1.1.0)
sinatra (1.0)
```

Any suggestions what's up here?

Comment: What is your ruby/rubygems version?

Comment: And incidentally, it's working in a small Sinatra App. I require mongo, create a connection and start using it...all golden.

Answer (score 4):

The example script doesn't require rubygems, which means that bson isn't going to be in your load path. If you add

```
require 'rubygems'
```

to the start of the script, I believe it will work.